# Can bokeh create facet_grid plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

In bokeh, we could create categorical coordinates plot.
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

[image]

Can I plot something like ggplot's facet_grid? Having two level X axis in different location. (top and bottom) Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not ideal:

- You cannot properly set the background color or minor titles (can be mitigated by switching to `Div`s instead of `Title`s with manual positioning)
- Plots don't have the same width/height due to the titles and axes (I don't know of any way to fix it)

```py
from random import random, randint

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import Div, Title
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh import layouts

major_x = ['Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Thur']
major_y = ['Female', 'Male']

minor_x = (0, 50)
minor_y = (0, 1)

height = 300
width = 300


def generate_datum(start, end):
    return random() * (end - start) + start


def generate_data():
    n = randint(10, 100)
    return dict(x=[generate_datum(*minor_x) for _ in range(n)],
                y=[generate_datum(*minor_y) for _ in range(n)])


full_data = {(x, y): generate_data() for x in major_x for y in major_y}


def pad_range(start, end):
    d = (end - start) * 0.1
    return start - d, end + d


def add_title(p, text, position):
    t = Title(text=text, align='center')
    p.add_layout(t, position)


column = []
for y in major_y:
    row = []
    for x in major_x:
        p = figure(x_range=pad_range(*minor_x), y_range=pad_range(*minor_y),
                   toolbar_location=None, tools='hover', width=width, height=height)
        p.xaxis.visible = (y == major_y[-1])
        p.yaxis.visible = (x == major_x[0])
        data = full_data[(x, y)]
        p.circle(x=data['x'], y=data['y'])
        if y == major_y[0]:
            add_title(p, x, 'above')
        if x == major_x[-1]:
            add_title(p, y, 'right')
        row.append(p)
    column.append(layouts.row(row))

major_y_label = f'''
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; height: {height * len(major_y)}px;">
  <div style="writing-mode: tb-rl; transform: rotate(-180deg); font-size: 1.5em;">
    tip/total_bill
  </div>
</div>
'''

major_x_label = f'''
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; width: {width * len(major_x)}px;">
  <div style="font-size: 1.5em;">
    total_bill
  </div>
</div>
'''

full_plot = layouts.grid([[Div(text=major_y_label), layouts.column(column)],
                          [None, Div(text=major_x_label)]])

show(full_plot)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure bokeh has anything straight out of the box to do this.  You would probably have to create the plot that you want, then run it through some sort of for loop and then use a [layout](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html).